# Use jQuery to change dropdown list value for navigation

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list whose options are the various sections of the page. The user will select an option and they will go to that specified section. When user scrolls on the page I want the dropdown to change to the value equivalent to the section of the page the is at. This is the dropdown:

```
<select name="ddlNavigation" id="ddlNavigation" class="form-control myDropdown" onchange="document.location = this.value;" style="width:100%;">
    <option value="#Introduction">Introduction</option>
    <option value="#EntryRequirements">Entry Requirements</option>
    <option value="#CourseStructure">Course Structure</option>
    <option value="#Application">Application</option>
</select>
...

<div id="Introduction" class="contentPanel" Name="Introduction">
    .. some content here
</div>

<div id="EntryRequirements" class="contentPanel" Name="Introduction">
    .. some content here
</div>
<div id="CourseStructure" class="contentPanel" Name="Introduction">
    .. some content here
</div>
<div id="Application" class="contentPanel" Name="Introduction">
    .. some content here
</div>
```

I have tried the following and when I scroll on the page, the page keeps jumping to the section and when I click on the dropdown I am unable to choose any value from the dropdown.

```
var introduction = $('#Introduction');
var entryRequirements = $('#EntryRequirements');
var courseStructure = $('#CourseStructure');
var application = $('#Application');

$(window).bind('mousewheel scroll DOMMouseScroll MozMousePixelScroll scrollstop', function (e) {
    if (introduction.length > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() < (introduction.height() + introduction.offset().top)) {
        $('#ddlNavigation').val('#Introduction').change();
    } else if ((entryRequirements.length > 0) && $(window).scrollTop() > (introduction.offset().top + introduction.height()) && $(window).scrollTop() < (entryRequirements.offset().top + entryRequirements.height())) {
        $('#ddlNavigation').val('#EntryRequirements').change();
    } else if ((courseStructure.length > 0) && $(window).scrollTop() > (entryRequirements.offset().top + entryRequirements.height()) && $(window).scrollTop() < (courseStructure.offset().top + courseStructure.height())) {
        $('#ddlNavigation').val('#CourseStructure').change();
    } else {
        $('#ddlNavigation').val('#Application').change();
    }
});
```

Comment: There's a whole lot of info in your code example that we don't know the values of, EG: entryRequirements and courseStructure.  If you can trim your example code down to the bare minimum, you will get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem is that you call the *`change()`* method on your options after setting them, which triggers the `onchange` event of the select. So every time you scroll, the select gets changed, then the `onchange` event gets triggered, and as you can not leave the current section so fast, it scrolls back to the beginning of the section. Leave the change() calls out, and it works nicely:

https://jsfiddle.net/k2yqujhb/

**EDIT:** As for the second problem: In your code is missing the anchor tags (`<a name="anchor">`) at the beginnings of your sections. But you probably forgot to copy&paste them here, as the first problem cannot explained without them. I can not explain the second problem with, them, though, so maybe there is still something missing, as the selecting does work in the fiddle.